# Passing quoted aurguments to bash function using a variable

Tags: string, bash, quoting

I am using bash and trying to do pass quoted arguments to a function using a string variable and it fails.

```
   myfunc() {
     for myarg in "${@}"
     do
       echo ">$myarg<"
     done
   }
  
   echo "prints three things"
   myfunc foo bar "blah blah"
  
   echo "uugh this prints four... why?!?!?"
   myvar="foo bar \"blah blah\""
   myfunc $myvar
```

produces this:

```
prints three things
>foo<
>bar<
>blah blah<
uugh this prints four... why?!?!?
>foo<
>bar<
>"blah<
>blah"<
```

I am building the list of arguments so that is why I need a string. Also, I am stuck with bash 4.2 version. Is there a way to have the second call to the function behave the same way as the first call?

Note: `myvar` is being read from a text file so I need that as a string.

Comment: Quote `myvar` such that the shell does not split it in 4 words before `myfunc` is executed: `myfunc "$myvar"`.

Comment: Unquoted `$mvvar` causes shell to split on every whitespace even inside the quotes

Comment: @RenaudPacalet if you quote `myvar` you end up with one thing instead of 3. I want to split it into 3 like if you pass it in directly.

Comment: Using `$myvar`, the content of the variable gets split on the spaces (this is called _word splitting_). This results in the four words `foo`, `bar`, `"blah` and `blah"`.

Comment: _I am building the list of arguments so that is why I need a string_: In such a case, use of an array should be preferred over a string. You may consider reading [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array for your arguments.

```
myvar=(foo bar "blah blah")

myfunc "${myvar[@]}"
```

---

You're relying on [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) with unquoted variable, that's should be fine if the [arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments)/strings does not contain white spaces or newlines or special character to the shell.

Comment: The "myvar" value is coming from a text file so it starting as a string.  It is equally challenging to convert string to an array when it has quotes.

Comment: Could you update the question and add some info about the input coming from a file. A simple input would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using zero separated arguments with `xargs` like this:

```
myfunc() {
  echo -en $myvar | xargs -I{} -0 echo ">"{}"<"
}

echo "uugh this prints four... why?!?!?"
myvar="foo\0bar\0blah blah\0"
myfunc $myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out my own question. The `eval` command might solve this with the least amount of fuss:

```
echo "uugh this prints four... why?!?!?"
myvar="foo bar \"blah blah\""
myfunc "$myvar"

eval myfunc $myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$myvar`, the content of the variable gets split on the spaces (this is called *word splitting*). This results in the four words `foo`, `bar`, `"blah` and `blah"`.

Of course in a real application, you would make `myvar` an **array**, where each element contains exactly that string you need to pass.

For example:

```
myvar=(foo bar "\"blah blah\""  "baz boom") # 4 elements
```

or whatever you like.

You would expand the array then by

```
myfunc "${myvar[@]}"
```